# 2 types of click events same code 2 results in winrt

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Strange behavior! when I click on the button on the metro app all works well, but when i click enter(the button on the KB) the only thing that happens is everything is cleared!

This fails

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            textBlock.Text = textBox1.Text;
           // textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

This works as expected

```
    private void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        textBlock.Text = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Do you have the AcceptButton property set?  Do you have KeyPreview set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best if when pressing Enter on the textbox, it will actualy simulate a click on the button, to assure that both actions are really the same.

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        this.Send.PerformClick();
    }
}

private void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBlock.Text = textBox1.Text;
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Also, as Chris mentioned, you shouldn't really handle the KeyDown even in this case: you can set the AcceptButton property of the form to be the Send button, which means that when pressing Enter, the button will be pressed - even if not focused. This sort of problem is a good example of why using the AcceptButton property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to handle focus when the user hits Enter. This is a common requirement in applications. As for your strange behavior, I can't explain it. But I am also not sure explaining it is as important as solving the problem. So, I can show you the easy implementation of handling enter and focus:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="White">One</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="T1" Width="1000" Height="100" KeyDown="T1_KeyDown_1" />
    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="White">Two</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="T2" Width="1000" Height="100" KeyDown="T2_KeyDown_1" />
</StackPanel>
```

and

```
private void T1_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        T2.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
}

private void T2_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        T1.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

The result is perfect focus control.